# Installed Ubuntu (14.04 LTS) "Trusty Tahr" on an "old" Window OS computer

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot

I recently installed Ubuntu (14.04 LTS) "Trusty Tahr" after install Ubuntu, I did not get the option to completed uninstall the Windows OS which is what I wanted to do and previously got an automatic prompt asking if I wanted to. What would be the best method in doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. first boot your Ubuntu
2. Install GParted if you haven't already. Launch it.
3. Find out the windows partition and delete it! (note backup all your data in windows partition). You can create a new partition out of it or resize adjacent partition to increase its size.
4. now run these commands in terminal:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

*Ask for help if you need for any of the above steps*

Comment: I'll try this and see if I have any issues.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the graphical application "GParted partition editor" to reduce the size of the Windows partition and increase the size of your Ubuntu partition.  'gparted' is a very powerful tool, so use cautiously.  I would assume you could delete the partition.  But not sure how the 'grub2' boot loader will react with the missing partition.

Comment: If you run `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` (just to make sure) and `sudo update-grub` afterwards GRUB will be OK.

Comment: @Eduardo, thanks for the additional info on the grub commands.   The 'grub-install /dev/sdb'  solved another issue I had.   My 'gparted'  partition copy  (my method of backup) to a USB drive, is now bootable by running this command.